# How much server RAM docker-machine instance needs?

Tags: docker, coreos, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a docker installed at OS X and using docker-machine with my host provider server. The server OS is CoreOS, I have 3 lightweight sites with NGINX, Mongo and MySQL instances. Sometimes sites down and provider's support suggesting me with low RAM, but 2GB RAM isn't sufficient for such sort of thing?

Comment: Depends on the tuning of the servers and the memory settings for the containers and the VM, but 2g is certainly tight.

Comment: Previously I had hosted exact this sites and DBs on a plan with 1GB RAM without docker and never got a downtime. Does docker do too much overhead?

Comment: Docker alone has little overhead, but if you run it in a VM... besides your applications might tune themself differently when they see more than 1gb.

Comment: If you used the default mysql containers you could possibly just get stuck with wrong settings for your applications. MySQL and MongoDB are adjustable to be smaller in RAM for your application based on the settings you provide but there is no "magic" "everything is perfect" setting for all applications.

Comment: So I'll try to go at 4GB RAM and leave results here after some weeks will pass.

Comment: @eckes I'm very glad for you, thanks for spending time here

Comment: You might need to adjust the settings anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL can consume tons of memory. Mongo by itself, too. You have both, probably at the standard settings. Push it to at least 4GB.